# FPDF russian cyrillic font

Tags: php, fpdf, cyrillic

I have problem with write cyrillic characters to page.
What I do:
I have font from bottom this article https://www.jelu.ru/2009/11/11.html
**CyrillicChancellor**

Next I try use

```
$pdi->SetFont('CyrillicChancellor','',20);
$txt = "AB русский текст! sśŻ";
$pdi->Write(0,$txt );
```

But output is ??????? how to write cyrillic characters?

I have to use FPDF and FPDI because I edit document